# Value of timeadded and timeraised is not appropriate in scom

Tags: powershell, scom

Partial output of the `get-scomalert | get-member -membertype property` in Powershell:

```
Name                              MemberType Definition
----                              ---------- ----------
TimeAdded                         Property   datetime TimeAdded {get;}
TimeRaised                        Property   datetime TimeRaised {get;}
```

Link for definition of both filed : [alert-logging-latency](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dirkbri/2014/08/19/analyzing-scom-2012-alert-logging-latency/)

> TimeRaised:
>       Timestamp, created when the Alert is raised on the agent.
>
> TimeAdded:
>       Timestamp, created when the Alert is written into the OpsMgr database.

How the value of timeadded and timeraised should be :

- As the defination suggests, timeadded should be greater (late) than timeraised as the alert will be raised first and then stored into the database.

The output of `get-scomalert | select name, timeraised, timeadded` in Powershell :

```
Name                                    TimeRaised                              TimeAdded
----                                    ----------                              ---------
All Management Servers Pool Unavaila... 5/14/2018 11:25:30 AM  <time raised^ >  5/14/2018 11:18:16 AM
All Management Servers Pool Unavaila... 5/14/2018 11:17:30 AM                   5/14/2018 11:10:16 AM
All Management Servers Pool Unavaila... 5/14/2018 11:09:30 AM                   5/14/2018 11:02:16 AM
All Management Servers Pool Unavaila... 5/14/2018 11:01:30 AM                   5/14/2018 10:54:16 AM
Power Shell Script failed to run        4/30/2018 4:26:53 PM   <time added^ >   4/30/2018 6:06:50 PM
Power Shell Script failed to run        4/30/2018 4:26:53 PM                    4/30/2018 6:06:50 PM
```

- **Why there are alerts for which timeadded is earlier than timeraised?**

Comment: I assume you've made sure your clocks are in sync

Comment: @JacobColvin Yes, They are almost in time sync. (maximum 1 minute of difference)

Comment: Why? That's a question specific to SCOM (i.e., not a programming quesiton).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart, You are absolutely right mate. I practically should not ask in SO. the reason is that I am used to ask questions here.. Anyway, Please let some folks answer the question, would be a great help.

Comment: I'm sure there's another stackexchange site that you could use. I kind of doubt anyone here will have an answer.